# GCP-Storage: do files appear before upload is complete

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage, google-compute-engine

I want to transfer files into a VM whenever there is a new file added to storage, the problem is that i want the transfer to be done only when the upload is complete

**So my question is :** Do files appear even when the upload is still going on ? which means if I build a program that looks for new files every second, would it transfer the files from gcs to VM even if the upload is incomplete or the transfer would start whenever the upload is complete and not while it is uploading ?

Comment: When I use gsutil, they appear as files in a temporary dir until the transfer is complete.

Comment: @Hitobat, what you are seeing is an artifact of gsutil's parallel uploading strategy. Several, temporary objects are created in parallel, and once they have all been uploaded, gsutil concatenates them into a single object and deletes the temporary objects. From the service's perspective, each of those temporary objects is a standalone object.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Google Cloud Storage uploads are `strongly consistent` for object uploads. This means that the object is not visible until the object is 100% uploaded and any Cloud Storage housekeeping (such as replication) is complete. You cannot see nor access an object until the upload has completed and your software/tool receives a success response.

[Google Cloud Storage Consistency](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/consistency)

> Do files appear even when the upload is still going on ? which means
>   if I build a program that looks for new files every second, would it
>   transfer the files from gcs to VM even if the upload is incomplete or
>   the transfer would start whenever the upload is complete and not while
>   it is uploading ?

No, your program will not see new objects until the new objects are 100% available. In Google Cloud Storage there are not partial uploads.

Answer (score 2):

Files do not appear in the UI of Cloud Storage until the file is completely upload it to the specified bucket by the user.

I attached you how Google Cloud Platform manage the consistency in Google Cloud Storage Buckets [here.](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/consistency)

You could use `gsutil` to list all the files in one of your Cloud Storage Buckets at any moment, as stated [here.](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/listing-objects)

As for the application you are trying to develop, I highly suggest you to use Google Cloud Functions, in conjunction with triggers.

In this case, you could use `google.storage.object.finalize` trigger in order to execute your function every time a new object is uploaded to one of your buckets. You can see examples of this application [here.](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/calling/storage#object_finalize)

The Cloud Function will ensure that your bucket is correctly uploaded to the bucket before attempting to transfer the object to your GCE instance.

Therefore, after completing the upload, the only thing left will be to execute `gcloud compute scp` to copy files to your Google Compute Engine via scp, as stated [here](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/compute/scp).

Comment: I can't use Cloud functions because we can't fix its IP adress ( it changes every time) and since vpc connector is still "beta" I can't use it to solve the ip issue, Hence the use of VM instead of CF.